# Styling radio buttons in tailwind css example does not work

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The example number four on [tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com), (after *Build whatever you want, seriously* (as of April 2021)) is a card, and the first type is *Simple* and the title of the card is *Classic Utility Jacket*.

This example contains a radio group, where you can choose the size of jacket, ranging from "XS" to "XL".

These radio buttons are styled in a way where the radio circles are not showing, selected button has a rounded rectangle and the labels are in the center of the rounded rectangle.

However, when I try the example my self, copy and pasting the example code into my project, the radio buttons does not look like anything in the example.

The same happens on the tailwind playground, and here is the example (never mind the picture missing):
https://play.tailwindcss.com/tOv207BJPm

I tried to install and use the $tailwindcss/forms plugin, but it didn't help much.

What am I missing to make the example work?

Comment: check updated tailwind playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/AYmTc4ISfn

Comment: Thank you, but it does not look like the original example by tailwindcss them selves. Here is how it looks on their webpages: https://i.imgur.com/cq3Lg1w.jpg - The thing is, since it is an original tailwind example, I think there must be something wrong with how I setup tailwind, missing some kind of setting pr plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need `@tailwindcss/forms` plugin for this.

Check out this https://youtu.be/pONeWAzDsQg video from Tailwind Lab